# Link 2 Select lists via jQuery to make them interchangable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 Select Lists, that I want to link via jquery so if I select option 1 in select list 1, it automatically selects option 1 in select list 2. And vise vera. Here are the 2 select lists:

```
<select class="form-control form-select required selectBox" id="edit-panes-delivery-address-delivery-ucxf-delivery-date" name="panes[delivery][address][delivery_ucxf_delivery_date]" style="display: none;"><option value="">Select a delivery date</option><option value="1464220800">Thursday 26/05/2016 Delivery (George to Plettenberg Bay)</option><option value="1464307200">Friday 27/05/2016 Delivery (George to Mossel Bay)</option><option value="1464825600">Thursday 02/06/2016 Delivery (George to Plettenberg Bay)</option><option value="1464912000">Friday 03/06/2016 Delivery (George to Mossel Bay)</option><option value="1465430400">Thursday 09/06/2016 Delivery (George to Plettenberg Bay)</option><option value="1465516800">Friday 10/06/2016 Delivery (George to Mossel Bay)</option></select>

<select class="form-control form-select required selectBox" id="edit-panes-billing-address-billing-ucxf-delivery-date" name="panes[billing][address][billing_ucxf_delivery_date]" style="display: none;"><option value="" selected="selected">- Select -</option><option value="1464220800">Thursday 26/05/2016 Delivery (George to Plettenberg Bay)</option><option value="1464307200">Friday 27/05/2016 Delivery (George to Mossel Bay)</option><option value="1464825600">Thursday 02/06/2016 Delivery (George to Plettenberg Bay)</option><option value="1464912000">Friday 03/06/2016 Delivery (George to Mossel Bay)</option><option value="1465430400">Thursday 09/06/2016 Delivery (George to Plettenberg Bay)</option><option value="1465516800">Friday 10/06/2016 Delivery (George to Mossel Bay)</option></select>
```

I did try the following but it seems to only work with text fields, or I'm doing something wrong:

```
$('#field1').change(function() {
  $('#field2').val($(this).val());
```

});

Note I can't edit the html itself (adding onchange= to the select lists). Is there no way it can be done without editing the select list itself?

Comment: What have you tried? Pretty straightforward - you have the logic down, and you can even use vanilla JS `onchange`

Comment: I tried something along the lines of this but it seems to only work with text fields: $('#field1').change(function() {
      $('#field2').val($(this).val());
});

Comment: Please include that in the question to help us out. And that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It would be like this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/cRqICQnZO2d77dYBnurh?p=preview

```
  <select class="form-control form-select required selectBox" 
  id="edit-panes-delivery-address-delivery-ucxf-delivery-date" 
  name="panes[delivery][address][delivery_ucxf_delivery_date]" 
  onchange="syncDropdownMenus(this, '#edit-panes-billing-address-billing-ucxf-delivery-date')"
  >
    <option value="">Select a delivery date</option>
    <option value="1464220800">Thursday 26/05/2016 Delivery (George to Plettenberg Bay)</option>
    <option value="1464307200">Friday 27/05/2016 Delivery (George to Mossel Bay)</option>
    <option value="1464825600">Thursday 02/06/2016 Delivery (George to Plettenberg Bay)</option>
    <option value="1464912000">Friday 03/06/2016 Delivery (George to Mossel Bay)</option>
    <option value="1465430400">Thursday 09/06/2016 Delivery (George to Plettenberg Bay)</option>
    <option value="1465516800">Friday 10/06/2016 Delivery (George to Mossel Bay)</option>
  </select>


  <select class="form-control form-select required selectBox" 
  id="edit-panes-billing-address-billing-ucxf-delivery-date" 
  name="panes[billing][address][billing_ucxf_delivery_date]"
  onchange="syncDropdownMenus(this, '#edit-panes-delivery-address-delivery-ucxf-delivery-date')"
  >
    <option value="" selected="selected">- Select -</option>
    <option value="1464220800">Thursday 26/05/2016 Delivery (George to Plettenberg Bay)</option>
    <option value="1464307200">Friday 27/05/2016 Delivery (George to Mossel Bay)</option>
    <option value="1464825600">Thursday 02/06/2016 Delivery (George to Plettenberg Bay)</option>
    <option value="1464912000">Friday 03/06/2016 Delivery (George to Mossel Bay)</option>
    <option value="1465430400">Thursday 09/06/2016 Delivery (George to Plettenberg Bay)</option>
    <option value="1465516800">Friday 10/06/2016 Delivery (George to Mossel Bay)</option>
  </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
      function syncDropdownMenus(targetedSelect, otherSelect) {
        var targetedSelectValue = jQuery(targetedSelect).val()
        jQuery(otherSelect).val(targetedSelectValue);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cant edit the html itself (adding onchange= to the select lists). Is there no way it can be done without editing the select list itself?

Comment: @xephox  has a good solution, [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cRqICQnZO2d77dYBnurh?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do this using only jQuery by using a [`.change()` event listener](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
var $dates = $('#edit-panes-billing-address-billing-ucxf-delivery-date, #edit-panes-delivery-address-delivery-ucxf-delivery-date');

$dates.change(function (e) {
    $dates.not(this).val($(this).val());
});
```

This should work on `input`, `textarea`, and `select` elements. The typical reason it might not be working in your instance on the select elements would be a mis-spelled selector.

Also note that a `select` elements's `.val()` uses the `value` attribute on the option, not the text within an option. Here's [more information](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/) in the jQuery FAQ.

Comment: ok, so the value that will be submitted will be the same, but visually, it wont display the text? I've added it and double checked the selectors, but visually its not updating...

Comment: Nevermind, was able to get it to work in jsfiddle, and then realized some stupid script was hiding that select list and replacing it with something else. This worked perfectly in the end! Thanks so much!

Comment: Now, above these fields is a "load previous address" where you can select old addresses, then the details change and you have to reselect the delivery date. It loads via ajax. the selector for the first select list then changes to #edit-panes-billing-address-billing-ucxf-delivery-date--2 ... I have edited the code to include this select list, but it doesnt link. Do I need to change the event type?

Comment: Or how could I modify it so that it doesnt act off an event... rather it joins the values together regardless (if it preloads with info for example)?